# Gmail could not verify that it actually came my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, amazon-route53, email-validation

I manage a domain in AWS Route53 and an email server in Microsoft (for the same domain).
Lately, emails from my domain to Gmail addresses are getting a warning message stating that "Gmail could not verify that it actually came from . Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments, or replying with personal information."

I've tried adding a DNSSEC signing, SPF and TXT records in Route 53 but it doesn't help :\

Any suggestions what I can do so Gmail won't show this warning?

The warning:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9gCo.png

Comment: Verify that the SPF and DKIM DNS resource records are correct. There are a number of Internet sites to test mail settings. I use this service often: https://mxtoolbox.com/dkim.aspx

Comment: Thanks! that helped me to find the missing DKIM I need to fix that!